# HTML5: How to include the <p> and <ul> tags in the same border style

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to put my paragraphs and un-ordered lists into the same border. At first I though it would just be as simple as putting the list *inside* the p tag... Unfortunately, that's not the case. A snippet of my external style sheet code will be included below.

```
p {
border-style: solid;
padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include all required elements to reproduce your problem. This includes both the CSS and HTML. You can use the [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) button to embed a runnable example into your question for us to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you want to nest both your p and ul elements inside of a div element, and then put a border around the div element to encompass both of them, like this:

```
<div>
  <p>Example</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Example</li>
    <li>Example</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then, in your css, do this:

```
div {
  border: solid black 2px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm pretty new to HTML and CSS, and have been grasping at straws for a bit.